# Spring 3.1 MVC: GET & POST on the same mapping, can it work?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring 3.1.

My webapp name is **"acme".**

The url is roughly **https://blah.blah.blah/acme**

That URL is set up to display the **login.jsp**

I have a "/login" mapping in my controller that my login.jsp submits to

If something goes wrong it return the user to the **login.jsp** with this url in the browser:
**https://blah.blah.blah/acme/login**

The "/login" mapping is set up to handle POST requests, so I am concerned about users bookmarking
**https://blah.blah.blah/acme/login**,  and getting the error message of  "GET request not supported"

So, I thought I would put in a function to handle GET requests to /login to reroute through my general mapping handler for "/" and "/home":

**Login.Controller.java**

```
package gov.noaa.acme.controller;

import java.security.Principal;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.*;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Controller
public class LoginController {


    private static final Logger logger  = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping({"/","home"})
    public String home(ModelMap model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Do some stuff

        return "login";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login_get(){
        logger.debug("started...");
        return "forward:home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("laph") LAPH laph, 
                        BindingResult bindingResult,
                        ModelMap model, 
                        HttpSession session,
                        HttpServletRequest request, 
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        @RequestParam(required=true) String last_usertype) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            logger.debug("Error returning home");
            return "home";
        }

        logger.debug("Started ....");  

        // Do authentication  


        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            model.put("status_message", error_message);       
            return "login";
        }

        // success, send newly authenticated user to a search page
        nextView = "search";
        return "redirect:" + nextView;
    }

}// end class LoginController
```

My logs show that I am not even reaching the controller method for handling GET requests for /login, I'm still getting the error messages that GET is not supported for /login.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am concerned about users bookmarking https:// blah.blah.blah/acme/login, and getting the error message of "GET request not supported".

Your method signatures are correct; with the annotations you have placed on `login_get` and `login`, Spring will not be confused and will invoke the correct methods for GET and POST requests.

Your method `home` is wrong; it returns the string `"login"`, but I guess you do not have a view named login and that you would like it to invoke one of the login methods. In that case you should have returned "forward:login", but this solution is not much better.

My advice is:

1. `/home` should render the home view, by using file `home.jsp` or whatever view technology you're using.
2. Use a [HandlerInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) to check whether a user is logged in, and if not, only then you redirect him to the login url.